# What does the MsiVerifyPackage WinAPI function do to verify an MSI?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-installer

The Windows documentation states that the MsiVerifyPackage function verifies that a file is an installation package. How much is verified here? If a byte in a content file is corrupted/incorrect, will this be caught? Or is it just a check that the MSI data is readable?

The MSDN page for the function is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370508(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This function doesn't check the package integrity. I've just tried to corrupt a package with a hex editor (from somewhere in the middle of the file to the end) and it returned `ERROR_SUCCESS` so it most probably check just *something* in the header of a file.

Comment: If you'd put that as an answer you'd have got some points!

Comment: @StephenHewlett: They didn't say what it did, just waht it didn't :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point of API's.  The SDK doco tells you what it does:

> The MsiVerifyPackage function verifies that the given file is an
>   installation package.

But what you are really asking is  "HOW" does it do what it does?  The whole point of an API is to abstract you from implementation details.  The question isn't answerable without access to the source code.  Even then, I'm not sure it should be answered as you might then rely on that behavior.

As an aside, what's your real problem?  I suspect this is more then idle curiosity and that there are some real questions in there somewhere.

Comment: Personally I suspect this was just a debug method put in the API during development to verify that the file was in fact an MSI database ( compound structured storage document ).    They probably wanted a way to check this without actually opening up the database and returning a handle.  In my 16 years of writing installers I've never needed to use this function.

Comment: My question is, to what extent is the package verified? How much can be wrong with it before it does not pass verification?

Comment: Open up a ticket with Microsoft and go ahold of the Windows Installer team and you just might get an answer to that question.  Otherwise it's unknowable. (That is unless you have some shared source agreement with Microsoft and can go look it up yourself.)